# schemaform adding the user input to a schema array

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

**Background**

I am making a form using [angular-schema-form](http://schemaform.io/)

**Setup**

I am trying to make an array of items that a user can make using a form. So, the user can add as many items into the array as they want.

For now the items in the array contain a command type.

Command Type should be a dropdown containing SSH, REST, and whatever the user enters in as the personalized command type.

**Code so far**

**SCHEMA**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "personalizedCommandType": {
      "title": "Personalized Command Type",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "commands": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Actions",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "commandType": {
            "title": "Command Type",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "REST",
              "SSH"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
   }
  }
}
```

**FORM**

```
[
  {
    "type": "help",
    "helpvalue": "<h5>Command</h5>"
  },
  {
    "key":"personalizedCommandType"
  },
  {
    "title":"Command",
    "key": "commands",
    "items": [
      "commands[].commandType"
    ]
  }
]
```

One can test this code here: http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html . Just copy and paste in my code.

**Question**

As one can see, the code I have now has a field with Personalized Command Type and an array of dropdowns with the 2 options SSH and REST. But I want to drop to also contain the value of the Personalized Command Type once the user has entered it.

**NOTE**

`copyValueTo` does not seem to have the functionality that I want given that it can only change values in the **model**, but I want it to change the enum array in the **schema**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`onChange`](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#onchange) option:

```
[
  {
    "type": "help",
    "helpvalue": "<h5>Command</h5>"
  },
  {
    "key":"personalizedCommandType"
     onChange: "updateSchema(modelValue,form)"
  },
  {
    "title":"Command",
    "key": "commands",
    "items": [
      "commands[].commandType"
    ]
  }
]
```

Update the Schema:

```
var defaultEnum = ["REST","SSH"];

$scope.updateSchema = function(modelValue,form) {
    var currentEnum = $scope.schema.commands.items.properties.commandType.enum;
    angular.copy(defaultEnum, currentEnum);
    if (modelValue) {
        currentEnum.push(modelValue);
    }; 
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormRedraw');
};
```